# django cms admin looks weird on heroku and unable to function

Tags: django, heroku, django-cms

I'm having a problem with django cms after pushing to heroku.

Django cms admin page is showing up without styling (plain html). Kindly refer to [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLd1I.jpg).

It should look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRm8e.jpg).

Django cms is also not functioning- such as unable to add pages.

Django cms looks and functions well on localhost.
For your advice please, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You staticfiles not coming on admin page

So you need to run command

`python manage.py collectstatic --noinput`

on **Heroku** server for **collectstatic** files and make you have correct `STATIC_ROOT` and `STATIC_URL` in settings of project

Comment: thank you, you were right it was due to wrong static files settings. thereafter heroku automatically runs collectstatic.